# jpg won't optimize (jpegtran, jpegoptim)

Tags: image, optimization, jpeg

I have an image and it's a jpg.

I tried running through jpegtran with the following command:

```
$ jpegtran -copy none -optimize image.jpg > out.jpg
```

The file outputs, but the image seems un-modified (no size change)

I tried jpegoptim:

```
$ jpegoptim image.jpg
image.jpg 4475x2984 24bit P JFIF  [OK] 1679488 --> 1679488 bytes (0.00%), skipped.
```

I get the same results when I use --force with jpegoptim except it reports that it's optimized but there is no change in file size

Here is the image in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVQ7x.jpg

But I can't seem to get it to work with any other jpegs I have either (only tried a couple though).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is possible the image has been run through these programs before?

Comment: It is, but I figured someone could suggest some lossy compression or maybe tell me it was an issue with jpeg encoding or something. I ended up taking a screenshot of the full picture and saving it as .png and converting that.

Comment: If you have done this once, it is unlikely that a second pass would produce any improvement. Similarly, if you take a JPEG and try to compress as ZIP, the file tends to get bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your image from imgur, but the size is 189,056 bytes. Is it possible that imgur did something to your image?

Anyway, I managed to optimize it to 165,920 bytes using [Leanify](https://github.com/JayXon/Leanify) (I'm the author) and it's lossless.

Comment: Leanify is able to make the jpeg smaller because it uses [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg), so if you only care about jpeg use mozjpeg.